# Use pre-trained word2vec in lstm language model?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, word2vec

I used tensorflow to train `LSTM` language model, code is from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py).

According to article [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-network-tutorial-part-4-implementing-a-grulstm-rnn-with-python-and-theano/), it seems that if I use pre-trained word2vec, it works better.

> Using word embeddings such as word2vec and GloVe is a popular method to improve the accuracy of your model. Instead of using one-hot vectors to represent our words, the low-dimensional vectors learned using word2vec or GloVe carry semantic meaning – similar words have similar vectors. Using these vectors is a form of pre-training.

So, I want to use `word2vec` to redo the training, but I am a little bit confused about how to do this.

The embedding code goes here:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  embedding = tf.get_variable(
      "embedding", [vocab_size, size], dtype=data_type())
  inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_.input_data)
```

**How can I change this code to use pre-trained `word2vec`?**