# Use LSTM tutorial code to predict next word in a sentence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, word2vec, word-embedding

I've been trying to understand the sample code with https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent
which you can find at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

(Using tensorflow 1.3.0.)

I've summarized (what I think are) the key parts, for my question, below:

```
 size = 200
 vocab_size = 10000
 layers = 2
 # input_.input_data is a 2D tensor [batch_size, num_steps] of
 #    word ids, from 1 to 10000

 cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(size) for _ in range(2)]
    )

 embedding = tf.get_variable(
      "embedding", [vocab_size, size], dtype=tf.float32)
 inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_.input_data)

inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, num=num_steps, axis=1)
outputs, state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
    cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state)

output = tf.reshape(tf.stack(axis=1, values=outputs), [-1, size])
softmax_w = tf.get_variable(
    "softmax_w", [size, vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b

# Then calculate loss, do gradient descent, etc.
```

My biggest question is *how do I use the produced model to actually generate a next word suggestion, given the first few words of a sentence*? Concretely, I imagine the flow is like this, but I cannot get my head around what the code for the commented lines would be:

```
prefix = ["What", "is", "your"]
state = #Zeroes
# Call static_rnn(cell) once for each word in prefix to initialize state
# Use final output to set a string, next_word
print(next_word)
```

My sub-questions are:

- Why use a random (uninitialized, untrained) word-embedding?
- Why use softmax?
- Does the hidden layer have to match the dimension of the input (i.e. the dimension of the word2vec embeddings)
- How/Can I bring in a pre-trained word2vec model, instead of that uninitialized one?

(I'm asking them all as one question, as I suspect they are all connected, and connected to some gap in my understanding.)

What I was expecting to see here was loading an existing word2vec set of word embeddings (e.g. using gensim's `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()`), convert each word in the input corpus to that representation when loading in each sentence, and then afterwards the LSTM would spit out a vector of the same dimension, and we would try and find the most similar word (e.g. using gensim's `similar_by_vector(y, topn=1)`).

Is using softmax saving us from the relatively slow `similar_by_vector(y, topn=1)` call?

---

BTW, for the pre-existing word2vec part of my question [Using pre-trained word2vec with LSTM for word generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42064690/841830) is similar. However the answers there, currently, are not what I'm looking for. What I'm hoping for is a plain English explanation that switches the light on for me, and plugs whatever the gap in my understanding is.　　[Use pre-trained word2vec in lstm language model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614097/use-pre-trained-word2vec-in-lstm-language-model) is another similar question.

**UPDATE:** [Predicting next word using the language model tensorflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33773661/841830) and [Predicting the next word using the LSTM ptb model tensorflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36286594/841830) are similar questions. However, neither shows the code to actually take the first few words of a sentence, and print out its prediction of the next word. I tried pasting in code from the 2nd question, and from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282697/841830 (which comes with a github branch), but cannot get either to run without errors. I think they may be for an earlier version of TensorFlow?

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** Yet another question asking basically the same thing: [Predicting Next Word of LSTM Model from Tensorflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42333101/841830)
It links to 
[Predicting next word using the language model tensorflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33773661/841830) (and, again, the answers there are not quite what I am looking for).

In case it still isn't clear, what I am trying to write a high-level function called `getNextWord(model, sentencePrefix)`, where `model` is a previously built LSTM that I've loaded from disk, and `sentencePrefix` is a string, such as "Open the", and it might return "pod".  I then might call it with "Open the pod" and it will return "bay", and so on.

An example (with a character RNN, and using mxnet) is the `sample()` function shown near the end of https://github.com/zackchase/mxnet-the-straight-dope/blob/master/chapter05_recurrent-neural-networks/simple-rnn.ipynb
You can call `sample()` during training, but you can also call it after training, and with any sentence you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of the time I needed to give the bounty, none of the answers worked for me; that is why I am leaving it un-ticked for the moment. I gave the bounty to the answer that appeared to be answering my key question most closely.

Comment: The answers didn't work for you because there is no generic answer for all language model implementation, each implementation is a little different. I think that this question should choose the level to ask, either intuitive understanding or specific code implementation. Not that I'm against the question though, I did up vote it. Actually if you have the understandings of the model and have fluency in Python, implementing would be not difficult. It takes time though, so if you posted your solution for this specific language model here after implemented it, it would be very useful for others.

Comment: @THN It was a bit more objective than that. By "didn't work" I meant I tried to implement the `getNextWord(model, sentencePrefix)` from each suggested answer, but they each either ended in exceptions being thrown, or had a gap in the explanation that was really the point of the question. If/when I get this working, I will self-answer. (BTW, thanks for being first to answer - it really helped me clarify my question, which led to finding more related questions.)

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am tackling the same problem!

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz No, not yet. So if you master it, please do post some code!

Comment: @DarrenCook I was very surprised that the tutorial did not include this, it is just the next logical step. I opened another question, let`s hope I dont get patronized as a "duplicate!". What I am after is 1.save the net to disk 2. invoke it whenever I want to get next 10 most probable word. Sure Ill post some code and if my question doesnt get answere I ll message the tensorflow guys for help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem!

Answer (score 7):

### Main Question

#### Loading words

Load custom data instead of using the test set:

```
reader.py@ptb_raw_data

test_path = os.path.join(data_path, "ptb.test.txt")
test_data = _file_to_word_ids(test_path, word_to_id)  # change this line
```

`test_data` should contain word ids (print out `word_to_id` for a mapping). As an example, it should look like: [1, 52, 562, 246] ...

#### Displaying predictions

We need to return the output of the FC layer (`logits`) in the call to `sess.run`

```
ptb_word_lm.py@PTBModel.__init__

    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.batch_size, self.num_steps, vocab_size])
    self.top_word_id = tf.argmax(logits, axis=2)  # add this line

ptb_word_lm.py@run_epoch

  fetches = {
      "cost": model.cost,
      "final_state": model.final_state,
      "top_word_id": model.top_word_id # add this line
  }
```

Later in the function, `vals['top_word_id']` will have an array of integers with the ID of the top word. Look this up in `word_to_id` to determine the predicted word. I did this a while ago with the small model, and the top 1 accuracy was pretty low (20-30% iirc), even though the perplexity was what was predicted in the header.

### Subquestions

> Why use a random (uninitialized, untrained) word-embedding?

You'd have to ask the authors, but in my opinion, training the embeddings makes this more of a standalone tutorial: instead of treating embedding as a black box, it shows how it works.

> Why use softmax?

The final prediction is **not** determined by the cosine similarity to the output of the hidden layer. There is an FC layer after the LSTM that converts the embedded state to a one-hot encoding of the final word.

Here's a sketch of the operations and dimensions in the neural net:

```
word -> one hot code (1 x vocab_size) -> embedding (1 x hidden_size) -> LSTM -> FC layer (1 x vocab_size) -> softmax (1 x vocab_size)
```

> Does the hidden layer have to match the dimension of the input (i.e. the dimension of the word2vec embeddings)

Technically, no. If you look at the LSTM equations, you'll notice that x (the input) can be any size, as long as the weight matrix is adjusted appropriately.

[image: LSTM equations]

> How/Can I bring in a pre-trained word2vec model, instead of that uninitialized one?

I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I think this might be along the right lines, but it still doesn't answer my key question: once I have a model built, I want to load it from disk, give it a string (the first few words in a sentence), and ask it to suggest the next word in the sentence.  I want to do that multiple times, with different prefix strings each time.  I.e. I'm trying to write a function with the signature: `getNextWord(model, sentencePrefix)`

Comment: I followed your instructions, but when I do `print(vals['top_word_id'])` I see `[[1 2]
 [1 1]
 [0 2]
...
[1 1]]`
I.e. not a single number I can pass to `word_to_id[]`. (I also didn't see how I can specify the sentence prefix, with this approach.)

Comment: When you're printing `vals['top_word_id']`, are you using the `test_config` or the `eval_config`? (Check the variable `num_steps`)You should be using the latter because you're evaluating the model. You can specify the sentence prefix by looking up words in `sentencePrefix` in `word_to_id`. Admittedly this approach is not the cleanest way to write the code

Answer (score 7):

> My biggest question is how do I use the produced model to actually generate a next word suggestion, given the first few words of a sentence?
>
> I.e. I'm trying to write a function with the signature: getNextWord(model, sentencePrefix)

Before I explain my answer, first a remark about your suggestion to  `# Call static_rnn(cell) once for each word in prefix to initialize state`: Keep in mind that `static_rnn` does not return a value like a numpy array, but a tensor. You can evaluate a tensor to a value when it is run (1) in a session (a session is keeps the state of your computional graph, including the values of your model parameters) and (2) with the input that is necessary to calculate the tensor value. Input can be supplied using input readers (the approach in the tutorial), or using placeholders (what I will use below).

Now follows the actual answer:
The model in the tutorial was designed to read input data from a file. The answer of @user3080953 already showed how to work with your own text file, but as I understand it you need more control over how the data is fed to the model. To do this you will need to define your own placeholders and feed the data to these placeholders when calling `session.run()`.

In the code below I subclassed `PTBModel` and made it responsible for explicitly feeding data to the model. I introduced a special `PTBInteractiveInput` that has an interface similar to `PTBInput` so you can reuse the functionality in `PTBModel`. To train your model you still need `PTBModel`.

```
class PTBInteractiveInput(object):
  def __init__(self, config):
    self.batch_size = 1
    self.num_steps = config.num_steps
    self.input_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, self.num_steps])
    self.sequence_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[])
    self.targets = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size, self.num_steps])

class InteractivePTBModel(PTBModel):

  def __init__(self, config):
    input = PTBInteractiveInput(config)
    PTBModel.__init__(self, is_training=False, config=config, input_=input)
    output = self.logits[:, self._input.sequence_len - 1, :]
    self.top_word_id = tf.argmax(output, axis=2)

  def get_next(self, session, prefix):
    prefix_array, sequence_len = self._preprocess(prefix)
    feeds = {
      self._input.sequence_len: sequence_len,
      self._input.input_data: prefix_array,
    }
    fetches = [self.top_word_id]
    result = session.run(fetches, feeds)
    self._postprocess(result)

  def _preprocess(self, prefix):
    num_steps = self._input.num_steps
    seq_len = len(prefix)
    if seq_len > num_steps:
      raise ValueError("Prefix to large for model.")
    prefix_ids = self._prefix_to_ids(prefix)
    num_items_to_pad = num_steps - seq_len
    prefix_ids.extend([0] * num_items_to_pad)
    prefix_array = np.array([prefix_ids], dtype=np.float32)
    return prefix_array, seq_len

  def _prefix_to_ids(self, prefix):
    # should convert your prefix to a list of ids
    pass

  def _postprocess(self, result):
    # convert ids back to strings
    pass
```

In the `__init__` function of `PTBModel` you need to add this line:

```
self.logits = logits
```

> Why use a random (uninitialized, untrained) word-embedding?

First note that, although the embeddings are random in the beginning, they will be trained with the rest of the network. The embeddings you obtain after training will have similar properties than the embeddings you obtain with word2vec models, e.g., the ability to answer analogy questions with vector operations (king - man + woman = queen, etc.) In tasks were you have a considerable amount of training data like language modelling (which does not need annotated training data) or neural machine translation, it is more common to train embeddings from scratch.

> Why use softmax?

Softmax is a function that normalizes a vector of similarity scores (the logits), to a probability distribution. You need a probability distribution to train you model with cross-entropy loss and to be able to sample from the model. Note that if you are only interested in the most likely words of a trained model, you don't need the softmax and you can use the logits directly.

> Does the hidden layer have to match the dimension of the input (i.e. the dimension of the word2vec embeddings)

No, in principal it can be any value. Using a hidden state with a lower dimension than your embedding dimension, does not make much sense, however.

> How/Can I bring in a pre-trained word2vec model, instead of that uninitialized one?

Here is a self-contained example of initializing an embedding with a given numpy array. If you want that the embedding remains fixed/constant during training, set `trainable` to `False`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
vocab_size = 10000
size = 200
trainable=True
embedding_matrix = np.zeros([vocab_size, size]) # replace this with code to load your pretrained embedding
embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding",
                            initializer=tf.constant_initializer(embedding_matrix),
                            shape=[vocab_size, size],
                            dtype=tf.float32,
                            trainable=trainable)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've pasted your code into the middle of ptb_word_lm.py. If I wanted to test it by, say,  having it output its next word suggestion for a test prefix after each epoch of training, do I create one instance of `InteractivePTBModel` at the top of main (e.g. just after I have config), or create it fresh each time within the loop (e.g. at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L512 )

Comment: I get "RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified." (on my first attempt to create the instance, inside the loop). Very long error message, but I think it is triggered by `self.input_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.batch_size, self.num_steps])`

Comment: Everytime you initialize `InteractivePTBModel` new operations are added to the computational graph. The error you are getting is caused by the fact that you initialize the graph inside a `managed_session` which is does not allow the graph to be modified. You can create the model [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L485), similarly to how the validation and test models are created. I hope this helps.

Comment: `self.input_data`  and `self.targets` appear to want to be in32 not float32. Unfortunately fixing that only got me to the next error (talking about shapes must be equal rank and strided slices). I'm still only trying to create an object of `InteractivePTBModel`, not even calling `get_next()` on it yet!  Was your code working for you?

Comment: You are right, the placeholders need to be int32 of course. I updated my answer. With the edits the equal rank error should also be fixed (which I believe was because `self.self.sequence_len` was defined as vector instead of a scalar). I don't have time to test the code right now.

Answer (score 4):

There are many questions, I would try to clarify some of them.

> how do I use the produced model to actually generate a next word suggestion, given the first few words of a sentence?

The key point here is, next word generation is actually word classification in the vocabulary. So you need a classifier, that is why there is a softmax in the output.

The principle is, at each time step, the model would output the next word based on the last word embedding and internal memory of previous words. `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn` automatically combine input into the memory, but we need to provide the last word embedding and classify the next word.

We can use a pre-trained word2vec model, just init the `embedding` matrix with the pre-trained one. I think the tutorial uses random matrix for the sake of simplicity. Memory size is not related to embedding size, you can use larger memory size to retain more information.

These tutorials are high-level. If you want to deeply understand the details, I would suggest looking at the source code in plain python/numpy.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added some pseudo code to my question: what I'm hoping for is an answer that shows me the real code, so I can actually print out the answer.

Comment: Re: "using softmax as it is word classification": with word embeddings, the cosine similarity is used to find the nearest word to our 300-dimension vector input. What I don't get is why we are using softmax, instead of doing that. Is it for speed (and if so, is there a trade-off), to give a simpler tutorial (e.g. no gensim dependency), better quality results, it is the only way to train the LSTM, or something else?

Comment: @DarrenCook word classification is the straight forward way to get the next word. Sure there are other ways, like your suggestion about embedding similarity, but there are no guarantee they would work better, as I don't see any more information used. Not to mention it would be difficult to compute the gradient. This answer only give an intuition, you may search for code in language model repos I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the code at the end of the answer.

---

Most of your questions (why a Softmax, how to use pretrained embedding layer, etc...) were answered I reckon. However as you were still waiting for a concise code to produce generated text from a seed, here I try to report how I ended up doing it myself.

I struggled, starting from the official Tensorflow tutorial, to get to the point were I could easily generate words from a produced model. Fortunately after taking some bits of answer in practically all the answers you mentioned in your question, I got a better view of the problem (and solutions). This might contains errors, but at least it runs and generates some text...

> how do I use the produced model to actually generate a next word suggestion, given the first few words of a sentence?

I will wrap the next word suggestion in a loop, to generate a whole sentence, but you will easily reduce that to one word only.

Let's say you followed the current tutorial given by tensorflow (v1.4 at time of writing) [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent), which will save a model after training it.

Then what is left for us to do is to load it from disk, and to write a function which take this model and some seed input and returns generated text.

---

## Generate text from saved model

I assume we write all this code in a new python script. Whole script at the bottom as a recap, here I explain the main steps.

### First necessary steps

```
FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS.model = "medium" # or whatever size you used
```

Now, quite importantly, we create dictionnaries to map ids to words and vice-versa (so we don't have to read a list of integers...).

```
word_to_id = reader._build_vocab('../data/ptb.train.txt') # here we load the word -> id dictionnary ()
id_to_word = dict(zip(word_to_id.values(), word_to_id.keys())) # and transform it into id -> word dictionnary
_, _, test_data, _ = reader.ptb_raw_data('../data')
```

Then we load the configuration class, also setting `num_steps` and `batch_size` to 1, as we want to **sample 1 word at a time** while the LSTM will process also 1 word at a time. Also creating the input instance on the fly:

```
eval_config = get_config()
eval_config.num_steps = 1
eval_config.batch_size = 1
model_input = PTBInput(eval_config, test_data)
```

### Building graph

To load the saved model (as saved by the `Supervisor.saver` module in the tutorial), we need first to **rebuild the graph** (easy with the `PTBModel` class) which must use the *same configuration* as when trained:

```
sess = tf.Session()
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-eval_config.init_scale, eval_config.init_scale)
# not sure but seems to need the same name for variable scope as when saved ....!!
with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
    tf.global_variables_initializer()
    mtest = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config, input=model_input)
```

### Restoring saved weights:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../Whatever_folder_you_saved_in')) # the path must point to the hierarchy where your 'checkpoint' file is
```

### ... Sampling words from a given seed:

First we need the model to contain an access to the logits outputs, or more precisely the probability distribution over the whole vocabulary.
So in the `ptb_lstm.py` file add the line:

```
# the line goes somewhere below the reshaping "logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.batch_size, ..."
self.probas = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="probas")
```

Then we can design some sampling function (you're free to use whatever you like here, best approach is sampling with a *temperature* that tends to flatten or sharpen the distributions), here is a basic random sampling method:

```
def sample_from_pmf(probas):
    t = np.cumsum(probas)
    s = np.sum(probas)
    return int(np.searchsorted(t, np.random.rand(1) * s))
```

And finally a function that takes a seed, your model, the dictionary that maps word to ids, and vice versa, as inputs and outputs the generated string of texts:

```
def generate_text(session, model, word_to_index, index_to_word, 
                  seed='</s>', n_sentences=10):
    sentence_cnt = 0
    input_seeds_id = [word_to_index[w] for w in seed.split()]
    state = session.run(model.initial_state)

    # Initiate network with seeds up to the before last word:
    for x in input_seeds_id[:-1]:
        feed_dict = {model.initial_state: state,
                     model.input.input_data: [[x]]}
        state = session.run([model.final_state], feed_dict)

    text = seed
    # Generate a new sample from previous, starting at last word in seed
    input_id = [[input_seeds_id[-1]]]
    while sentence_cnt < n_sentences:
        feed_dict = {model.input.input_data: input_id,
                     model.initial_state: state}
        probas, state = session.run([model.probas, model.final_state],
                                 feed_dict=feed_dict)
        sampled_word = sample_from_pmf(probas[0])
        if sampled_word == word_to_index['</s>']:
            text += '.\n'
            sentence_cnt += 1
        else:
            text += ' ' + index_to_word[sampled_word]
        input_wordid = [[sampled_word]]

    return text
```

---

## TL;DR

Do not forget to add the line:

```
self.probas = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='probas')
```

In the `ptb_lstm.py` file, in the `__init__` definition of `PTBModel` class, anywhere after the line `logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.batch_size, self.num_steps, vocab_size])`.

The whole script, just run it from the same directory where you have `reader.py`, `ptb_lstm.py`:

```
import reader
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from ptb_lstm import PTBModel, get_config, PTBInput

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS.model = "medium"

def sample_from_pmf(probas):
    t = np.cumsum(probas)
    s = np.sum(probas)
    return int(np.searchsorted(t, np.random.rand(1) * s))

def generate_text(session, model, word_to_index, index_to_word, 
                  seed='</s>', n_sentences=10):
    sentence_cnt = 0
    input_seeds_id = [word_to_index[w] for w in seed.split()]
    state = session.run(model.initial_state)

    # Initiate network with seeds up to the before last word:
    for x in input_seeds_id[:-1]:
        feed_dict = {model.initial_state: state,
                     model.input.input_data: [[x]]}
        state = session.run([model.final_state], feed_dict)

    text = seed
    # Generate a new sample from previous, starting at last word in seed
    input_id = [[input_seeds_id[-1]]]
    while sentence_cnt < n_sentences:
        feed_dict = {model.input.input_data: input_id,
                     model.initial_state: state}
        probas, state = sess.run([model.probas, model.final_state],
                                 feed_dict=feed_dict)
        sampled_word = sample_from_pmf(probas[0])
        if sampled_word == word_to_index['</s>']:
            text += '.\n'
            sentence_cnt += 1
        else:
            text += ' ' + index_to_word[sampled_word]
        input_wordid = [[sampled_word]]

    print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    word_to_id = reader._build_vocab('../data/ptb.train.txt') # here we load the word -> id dictionnary ()
    id_to_word = dict(zip(word_to_id.values(), word_to_id.keys())) # and transform it into id -> word dictionnary
    _, _, test_data, _ = reader.ptb_raw_data('../data')

    eval_config = get_config()
    eval_config.batch_size = 1
    eval_config.num_steps = 1
    model_input = PTBInput(eval_config, test_data, name=None)

    sess = tf.Session()
    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-eval_config.init_scale,
                                            eval_config.init_scale)
    with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
        tf.global_variables_initializer()
        mtest = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config, 
                         input_=model_input)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('../models'))

    while True:
        print(generate_text(sess, mtest, word_to_id, id_to_word, seed="this sentence is"))
        try:
            raw_input('press Enter to continue ...\n')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\b\bQuiting now...')
            break
```

---

## Update

As for restoring old checkpoints (for me the model saved 6 months ago, not sure about exact TF version used then) with recent tensorflow (1.6 at least), it might raise an error about some variables not being found (see comment).
In that case, you should update your checkpoints using [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/tools/checkpoint_convert.py).

Also, note that for me, I had to modify this even further, as I noticed the `saver.restore` function was trying to read `lstm_cell` variables although my variables were transformed into `basic_lstm_cell` which led also to `NotFound Error`. So an easy fix, just a small change in the `checkpoint_convert.py` script, line 72-73, is to remove `basic_` in the new names.

A convenient way to check the name of the variables contained in your checkpoints is (`CKPT_FILE` is the suffix that comes before `.index`, `.data0000-1000`, etc..):

```
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(CKPT_FILE)
reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
```

This way you can verify that you have indeed the correct names (or the bad ones in the old checkpoints versions).

Comment: Thanks a lot, https://stackoverflow.com/users/5303618/h-rev. The code looks promising, but I cannot get it to work. I get the following error. Any idea how to fix it?

File "test.py", line 64, in <module>
    mtest = PTBModel(is_training=False, config=eval_config, input_=model_input)
...
ValueError: Variable Model/RNN/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

Comment: At the time of writing it worked, and now indeed, I get same error (with tensofrlow 1.6+).
The issue arises if you saved the model with an earlier version and restore with a recent one. The naming convention for LSTM parameters changed, e.g. `cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/weights` became `cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel`. Which is why you cannot restore them if you try to restore old checkpoints with recent TF (so bad...). Use [this  script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/tools/checkpoint_convert.py) to update your checkpoints. (See update in answer)

Comment: @NiklasHeidloff Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same problem. I'm trying to use the checkpoint right after storing it. So at least in my case the reason can't be the difference between versions.