# Tensorflow RNN tutorial, feeding data to the net and getting results

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Thanks to a helpful user here I was able to run this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent and set it up so it it periodically runs with data from my chatbot. 
Thankyou SO.

Now, since it gives consistently low perplexity I would now like to well.. have it predict the next world and tell it to me.

For what I understand I need to    (1) save the network after training it    (2) call a function that feed the net the phrase and gets the array of possible next word and the associated probability.

How to? I wasn't able to gather this from the tutorial, help is very appreciated :)

Comment: question 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125018/use-lstm-tutorial-code-to-predict-next-word-in-a-sentence/

Comment: @user3080953 hey! Thankyou! I actually used search and failed! :-)

Comment: Tho that question is basically the same still I doest answer about how to save the trained net to the computer drive and then reload it at later time, Im after this one too

Comment: Yup, that's why I didn't mark as duplicate